# Finite sum on Negative Binomial

Tags: summation

I am trying to work these out:
$$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{k}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   r+u  \\
   u  \\
\end{matrix} \right){{\left( {\alpha} \right)}^{u}}{{\left( {1-\alpha} \right)}^{r+1}}}$$
$$\sum\limits_{u=0}^{k}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   r+u  \\
   u  \\
\end{matrix} \right){{\left( \alpha  \right)}^{u}}{{\left( 1-\alpha  \right)}^{r+1}}\sum\limits_{m=u+r+1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{e}^{-\lambda }}{{\lambda }^{m}}}{m!}}}$$

Thanks!

Comment: You can have a closed form for the sum in terms of the hypergeometric function.

Comment: What is $k$? If "sufficiently large" (so that you can live with $k \rightarrow \infty$), then $\binom{-r - 1}{u} = (-1)^u \binom{r + u}{u}$, and you have a good approximation for the first sum if $\lvert \alpha \rvert$ is small.

Comment: Thanks @ Mhenni Benghorbal. I found that also I can use  regularized beta function too.

Comment: Thanks @ vonbrand. I can definitely use that for approximation, in some case k could be quite large.
For the second integral, I was trying to change the order of summations, see if that helps.